# The sum of the product of two binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

This is really phsycics related question with mathematics behind it.

In my physics book there's the following relation:

$$\sum\binom{x_a+y_a-1}{x_a}\binom{x_b+y_b-1}{x_b}=\binom{x_a+x_b+y_a+y_b-1}{x_a+x_b}$$

For $x_a+x_b=c$ with $c$ some constant. (e.g. you can summarize when $x_a=1$ and $x_b=2$ for a total of $x_a+x_b=3$, but also $x_a=2$ and $x_b=1$, etc. any value from $x_a=0$ or $x_b=0$ is allowed. I'm sorry if this notation is not mathematical enough.)

I'm having some trouble deriving what's on the right hand side of the equals sign. If anyone could give some pointers or something that'd be nice. `:-)`

Comment: Summing over $x_a$ but $x_a$ appears in the RHS? What the...

Comment: @Did, that's because you are summing over $x_a+x_b=c$, and thus, in the RHS only constants appear

Comment: Thus, rewrite things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Vandermonde identity. Proofs can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: I don't understand though, Chu-Vandermonde identity applied correctly should give -2 in the top term of the binomial on the RHS no?